# Django set ModelForm field without including it in the form

Tags: django, forms

In my app, I have `User`s create `Post` objects. Each `Post` has a `User`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I want to create a post-submission form for editing and submission, so I plan to use Django's ModelForm functionality.

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
```

However, if I do this, then whoever is viewing the form will be able to set who the Post author is. I want to make sure that the resulting `user` field is them. But, if I exclude the `user` field from the ModelForm,

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = 'user'
```

then the user will not be set on form submission. I've hacked my way around this by making a custom form and updating the post field

```
def submit_view(request):
    .... 
    request.POST = request.POST.copy()
    request.POST.update({
        'user' : request.user.id
    })

    form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    ....
```

but then I lose automatic UI generation and form validation, which in some ways defeats the purpose of the `Form` class. Could somebody point me to the idiomatic way of setting the `user` field without including it in the `Form`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this view:

```
def submit_view(request):
   form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
   if form.is_valid():
      new_post = form.save(commit=False)
      new_post.user = request.user
      new_post.save()
```

Comment: can I exclude the `user` field from the ModelForm in this case?

Comment: yes, you should if yout dont want it to be renderred! The user is stored directly in the model instance!

Comment: thanks, for some reason I thought it was going to be more complicated than that...

Answer (score 0):

view.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Post

class PostCreate(CreateView):
   model = Post
   template_name  ="new_Post_form.html"
   fields = ['text']

   def form_valid(self, form):
      object = form.save(commit=False)
      object.user = self.request.user
      object.save()
      return super(PostCreate, self).form_valid(form)
   def get_success_url(self):
      return "/"
```

url.py

```
url(r'^newpost$',views.PostCreate.as_view(),name='post_new',),
```

new_post_form.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form" action="newpost" id="new-post-form">
<div class="modal-body">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```